# gunzip chunked response over TCP in node.js using zlib

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, zlib, chunked-encoding

Node.js v9.2.1

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to forgo the header check when using the built in zlib module in node.js?
2. What exactly is zlib looking for during this 'header check'?/can I just spoof it?

All the examples I've seen are using some kind of library(http, request) that implement atleast some kind of header parsing prior to hitting zlib. So what zlib is actually seeing doesn't seem the be the raw response. Also in these examples an 'end' event is fired on the closing of the connection. My example will have no such event.

---

For this question lets assume I'm using a dead simple net.Socket with a persistent TCP connection as follows:

```js
var net = require('net');
var chunks = [];
var socket = net.connect({
  port: foo,
  host: bar
}, () => {
  socket.write('<perfectRequestHeaders>', null, () => {
    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    })
  })
})
```

And then later when I decide all the chunks have been received. *(There is no 'end' event as the connection remains open. I only know the response in complete once I've seen the terminating chunk)*

```js
var zlib = require('zlib');
var resBuffer = Buffer.concate(chunks);
var headerEndIndex = resBuffer.indexOf('\r\n\r\n');
var headerBuffer = resBuffer.slice(0, headerEndIndex),
  bodyBuffer = resBuffer.slice(headerEndIndex + 4);
// assume headerBuffer & bodyBuffer are what their names imply

function bodyParser(bodyBuffer) {
  // assume it parses out all the stuff that
  //      isn't part of the actual chunked data
  return parsedBodyBuffer;
}


// complains about header check
// what must be done to stop zlib from whining???
zlib.gunzipSync(bodyParser(bodyBuffer)).toString('utf-8');
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you.